# avahi gives correct ip for local name, but ssh connects to 127.0.0.2

Tags: avahi, resolvconf

I have a current bullseye debian system with avahi installed and observe a puzzling problem:

```
avahi-resolve gais.local -n4
```

returns:

```
gais.local  10.0.0.106
```

which seems correct. However, `ping` or `ssh` for gais.local goes to the ip `127.0.0.2`:

```
ping gais.local
PING gais.local.rpz.GS.local (127.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.2 (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.2 (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
```

and

```
ssh gais.local -v
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
...
debug1: Control socket "/home/frank/.ssh/frank@gais.local:22" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to gais.local [127.0.0.2] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

I checked that `resolvconv` is installed and running. What is missing?

Compared to another installation where I did not see this problem, I use here a different router (tp-link MR6400), but cannot see, how this would influence avahi.

Comment: What is the order of entries on the `hosts` line of your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file?

Comment: it is: `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
` -- never checked this file? how is it used?

Comment: So is there an entry for `gais.local` in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: no, and I would rather not put one. I prefer to use avahi.

Comment: I wasn't going to suggest you put one there - I was curious if there was one already, since `files` would override `mdns4_minimal` (avahi) according to the nsswitch file

Comment: i have the impression that I could put the host name in `hosts`, but then I had to add all of it there and needed to maintain them. avahi or something similar seems to be the better solution. I mostly wonder, why it worked before and I encounter difficulties... Thank you for your suggestions. What should I put in `nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: I don't recommend changing either of those files - they don't seem to be the problem here

Comment: Any other suggestion? I have double checked everything and cannot find the cause of the problem!

Comment: No sorry I don't - if it was *just* ssh I'd suggest checking the ssh config files (`~/.ssh/config`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) however the fact that you see the same behavior from `ping` suggests it's something deeper in the hostname resolution stack. I can't think of anything short of running an `strace` on `ping` that might throw light on that.